# WriteFields in Firestore Rules only working in Simulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

A big problem I am having with Firestore Rules is that using the Simulator in the Firebase Console to simulate database accesses does not correspond to the behavior I am seeing from my clients. Now I have stumbled accross an issue that I cannot seem to fix.

#### Issue

The following syntax *works fine* in the *simulator*:

```
allow create: if request.writeFields.hasAll(["a", "b", "c"]);
```

When requesting with the *exact same* fields from my Android client, I get `Error performing setData, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`.

The request (simplified) looks as follows:

[image: simulator]

By setting `allow create;` (simplified) I have verified and identified that the problem has to be connected to `request.writeFields` because my requests, only from my real clients, fail as soon as I add logic regarding that.
*The simulated data access* is **allowed** in **all** my tests.

My reference is the [`List` interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List).

#### Question

I am wondering if I am either missing something about [`writeFields`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#writeFields) (potentially connected to `allow create`) and also how I am regularly seeing disparities between simulated and real accesses.
Keep in mind that my syntax works perfectly fine in the simulator, but a real request containing the exact same JSON data fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use map diffs to solve this issue instead of writeFields:

```
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAll(["a", "b", "c"]);
```